# When use annotation @Parameters, I get 2 error messages "The annotation @Parameter is disallowed for this location" . Not sure why?

Tags: java, testng

I have been following some blogs & the testng site to get this working, the idea behind using parameters is to pass the browser value from testng.xml file. But when I put the @Parameters annotaion error comes up in eclipse before running the script. Error comes up when I try to validate the code -

**Error Message**

*Multiple markers at this line
    - The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type 
     Parameter
    - Parameter cannot be resolved to a type
    - The annotation @Parameter is disallowed for this location*

Think something is a miss here maybe a wrong import or some syntax error. I have done also done import for

```
import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;
import com.beust.jcommander.Parameters;
```

But does not work. Have tried to put the @Parameters annotation below the @Test, but even that does not work.

Here is my code -

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class first_class {
    private Selenium selenium;
    public String url = "http://google.com/";   

    @Parameter ({ "browser" })
    @Test   
    public void Test(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capability.setBrowserName(browser);

        WebDriver driver = null;
        try {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:".concat(
                    "4444").concat("/wd/hub")), capability);
            System.out.println();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println("In Test Methos");
        selenium.open("http://www.google.com/"); 
        System.out.println(selenium.getTitle() + "in in Test Method");
        selenium.close();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong annotation, please read the TestNG Javadoc:

http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Parameters.html

Comment: OK, it worked. Not sure why it didnot earlier as I had tried **@Parameters** as well. Thanks for the support though.

Answer (score 0):

Even i caught kind of error in my program
Try to write @before , @after or @test annotation before @parameter annotation

Answer (score 0):

Use @parameters instead of @parameter